# Matrix error LWJGL

Tags: matrix, glsl, lwjgl, opengl-4

I made this little game engine but when I setup matrix in shader GLSL position got annulled by it and any image goes displayed...
Here GLSL program:

```
            "#version 450 core\n" +
                "layout(location=0) in vec2 in_Position;\n" +
                "layout(location=0) uniform mat4 uni_Model;\n" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "   gl_Position = uni_Model * vec4(in_Position, 0.0f, 1.0f);\n" +
                "}";
```

Here's my matrix:

```
            Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();
        matrix.translate(new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)); // I know it don't translate anything, it was just a test
        matrix.scale(new Vector3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)); // I know it don't scale anything, " " "
        FloatBuffer modelBuffer = FloatBuffer.allocate(16);
        matrix.store(modelBuffer);

        glUniformMatrix4fv(0, false, modelBuffer); // 0 is the location of the uniform
```

If I remove matrix from GLSL and from Java Code the program works fine, it means that the Matrix has null values and cancels gl_Position value.
Finally here's my output:
https://gyazo.com/99bddae6e7dbf8165940e15632d41e83
I clear screen of blue color each frame.

Comment: You do know that gl_Position wants to receive "normalized device coordinates"?  So unless in_Position gives normalized device coordinates, an identity matrix would not do the desired conversion.

Comment: @St0fF: He said that his code works *without* the matrix. So passing an identity matrix should not affect anything.

Comment: @NicolBolas is right

Answer (score 1):

I solved! The problem was I forgot to call `modelBuffer.flip()` but *only replacing it, it gave me a native error*. So I found another issue in FloatBuffer initliazation: I replaced `FloatBuffer.allocate(16)` with `BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16)` and now all **works fine** :)